# regex multliline string for ace

Tags: javascript, regex, string, multiline, ace-editor

I have written regex to highlight a multiline string and tested it on regexr.com which provides the correct highlighting. But this does not work work when tested in Kitchen Sink.

regexexpr:  `(["]\n(['].*\n)*(\s)*["])`

```
{
token : "multistring", // multi line string
regex : '(["]\n([\'].*\n)*(\s)*["])'
}
```

**Files:**

css: [pastebin](http://pastebin.com/jvUkEfMk)

highlighting_rules: [pastebin](http://pastebin.com/EhLEuKTD)

**Regex Rules:**

The regex should start with a Quote ("), end with a quote (") as the first character on the line. And in between, each line should start with an apostraphy (').

**Valid Multiline Examples:**

```
//1=========================
"
'This
     "

//2=========================
"
'This
'That
"

//3=========================
"
'This
'That
 "

//4=========================
"
'This
'That
     "
```

**Invalid Multiline Examples:**

```
//5=========================
"
WRONG'This
"

//6=========================
"Stuff
'This
"
```

Any help would be highly appreciated!

Comment: Please [edit] your question to post the actual JavaScript code you're using. How are you going from the string you posted to a RegExp object?

Comment: I have edited the post and included more information that this is about Ace and not just Javascript. The regex is saved as a string in a variable and passed later in in the ace library. You can see the syntax in thew highlight_rules link on line 49. Thanks

Comment: The ace tag is for the ACE C++ library, doesn't seem the library you are using

Comment: The issue at the moment is Ace reads line by line. SO the regex I posted would never work.

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing here, but it could be that Kitchen Sink is automatically setting the `single line`/`DOTALL` modifier, which makes `.` match `new line`. And since your regex uses `.*` (which *never* is good) that eats up everything between first part of `//1` and last line of `//6`.

What if you try

```
regex : '"\\n(?:\'[^\\n]*\\n)*\\s*"'
```

which is *basically* the same as yours. Removed some unnecessary stuff, and most importantly, changed your `.*` to `[^\n]` - matching everything but `new line`.

Hope this helps.

Regards

**Edit:**

Reading through my answer I realize - I forgot to escape the backslashes - as did You. Changed the regex. Hope it works now.

Comment: Thank you for your response. This code would work. but unfortunately Ace reads line by line instead of per document. So \n isn't a possibility sadly. Need some more Ace syntax in there haha

Answer (score 0):

As ace reads line by line `\n` does not work in regex.

I found these links helpful: [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21300764/how-to-highlight-the-first-word-in-each-line-in-ace-editor) [link2](http://www.it1me.com/it-answers?id=35289002&ttl=ACE%20Editor%20multiline%20regex)

```
{ // Multiline String
            token : 'multistring', // Start
            regex : '["]$',
            push : [
                {
                    token: 'multistring',
                    regex:/^(\s*'.*)/ // middle
                },
                {
                    token: 'multistring',
                    regex:/^\s*["]/, // end
                    caseInsensitive:true,
                    next:"pop"
                },
                {defaultToken:"testerx"} // Everything else that does not match
            ]
        }
```